# Is it possible for an Azure Web App to directly authenticate, or federate to a registered application within a B2C tenant? If so, how?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

Apologies if my terminology is a little off here. I'm developing a web app with a React front-end, Express server and Postgres DB. Everything is on Azure, as per company preference, with everything I just mentioned within our organisation's AAD tenant. I've created an AAD B2C tenant for authenticating users, and want to perform operations, via the Microsoft Graph API, on that B2C tenant from the Express server that's hosted on an Azure App Service.

Setting up certificate authentication for Graph, I realised that I'd need to manually upload the private key to the server or keep them in Azure Key Vault. Opting for the latter (our zip-deploy/run-as-package setup means each deployment would mean re-uploading the key), I noticed that the `@azure/identity` package uses the servers' managed identity to authenticate with AAD and get a token for Key Vault, for which the server has access rights.

It seems a bit... 'roundabout' that the express Web App seamlessly authenticates, gets a token, for me to then redeem that token to retrieve the private key, which I then use to authenticate as the B2C-registered application and access the Graph API.

I can't tell if I'm being really daft -- despite them being in different tenants, is there a way that the server can more-directly authenticate with the B2C tenant? Is there a facility for cross-tenant permissions?

Many thanks for any advice offered.

Comment: You’re doing it the best way, in terms of security.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to authenticate cross tenant if yes then you could think of AAD app registration and there you can configure other tenant.